# Does eval() run in strict mode in methods?

Tags: javascript

Does eval() run in strict mode in methods?

```
class A { b() {eval("with(this) { 1 } ")} }
new A().b()
// strict mode error
```

But not in functions?

```
function b() {eval("with(this) { 1 }")}
b()
> 1
```

Comment: Sure `eval` runs. But `with` is not allowed in there. Have you actually looked at the error message?

Answer (score 2):

This is explicitly stated in docs [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Strict_mode), [ES2017](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/#prod-ClassBody).

> The bodies of class declarations and class expressions are executed in
>   strict mode i.e. constructor, static and prototype methods, getter and
>   setter functions are executed in strict mode.